# using mongodump's query parameter with a Date

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Using `mongodump` with it's `query` parameter fails when using a query with the Date constructor. Does anyone know why this is? E.g.

`mongodump --db myDB --collection myCollection --query '{dateCreated:{$gte:new Date("2016/5/18"),$lt:new Date("2016/5/19")}}'`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: avoiding the date constructor altogether:

`mongodump --db myDB --collection myCollection --query '{dateCreated:{$gte:new Date(1463544000000),$lt:Date(1463630400000)}}'`